# Match a column of id with different items from a list in another column in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this:

[image]

The column "ID" is the patient ID. The column "Codes" is a list of ICD codes of the patient.
Since the number of codes for each patient is different, I can't figure out how to make it into a wide dataframe first.
I hope to match each code in the list to its "ID" and make a long dataframe like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this? Thank you!

This is the output I expect:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO, Li Liu! Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly into a [code block].

Comment: One reason this is so important _here_ is that with the original data, it's not abundantly clear if the `Codes` column is a list-column or if it has embedded strings that look like R expressions.

Comment: Having said that, seeing `c(...)` in a column when you aren't intending to make list-columns (e.g., using `tidyr::nest`) suggests that something earlier in your processing made it a list without your knowledge. Perhaps it would be useful to revisit the previous sections of code to determine when `Codes` was created (as a list) or when it changed from a "normal" column to a list-column (or a R-expression rendition of data that should never have been converted to that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the data is this:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 2817:2813, Codes = list(c("J45.909", "A53.9", 
"Z87.898"), c("H26.499", "C90.00", "H40.9", "F41.9", "C50.919"
), c("163.50", "110", "E78.00", "E06.3", "K11.8"), c("148.91", 
"142.9", "Z95.810", "R62.7", "K57.92"), c("R91.1", "E11.40", 
"Z79.4", "E78.00", "110", "D12"))), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

You can just use `unnest()`:

```
df |> unnest(Codes)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 24 × 2
      ID Codes  
   <int> <chr>  
 1  2817 J45.909
 2  2817 A53.9  
 3  2817 Z87.898
 4  2816 H26.499
 5  2816 C90.00 
 6  2816 H40.9  
 7  2816 F41.9  
 8  2816 C50.919
 9  2815 163.50 
10  2815 110    
# ℹ 14 more rows
```